# Problem in finding limit function of $f_n(x)=1-(1-x^2)^{n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Its answer is $f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{when $x=0$ } \\
1, & \text{when $0<\vert x \vert< \sqrt 2$}
\end{cases}$.

I'm not getting how second line of $f(x)$ came?

Apologies if the post is too basic, but I've invested a great time in understanding this but of no use.

Any hints are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x=0,$ then $f_n(x) = 0 $ for all $n,$ hence $f_n(0) \to 0.$ If $|1-x^2|< 1,$ then $(1-x^2)^n \to 0,$ hence $f_n(x) \to 1.$ The set corresponding to $|1-x^2|< 1$ is $0<|x| < \sqrt 2.$ If $|x|= \sqrt 2,$ then $f_n(x) = 1-(-1)^n,$ which has no limit. If $|x| > \sqrt 2,$ then $(1-x^2)^n$ is unbounded and oscillates wildly, so there is no limit. Thus there is no limit unless $|x| < \sqrt 2,$ and in that interval the limit function is $f(0) = 0, f(x) = 1, 0<|x|<\sqrt 2.$

Comment: Small nitpick: "Thus there is no limit unless $\lvert x\rvert < \sqrt{2}$" (strict inequality).

Comment: Small nitpicks are welcome, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the limit as $n\to\infty$, then you need $|1-x^2|<1$. This is the open interval $(0,\sqrt 2)$. So
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{when $x=0$ } \\
1, & \text{when } 0<x< \sqrt 2.
\end{cases}
$$
For $x\geq \sqrt 2$ or $x<0$ the limit does not exist, since $|1-x^2|>1$.

Comment: Did you mean to write a strict inequality in your last line? It should be $x <0$, the limit for $x=0$ clearly exists (and you wrote it).

Comment: @Martin Argerami:Sorry for mistyping the function.I  got it

Comment: @ClementC.:    yes

Comment: @Martin Argerami:in your answer in place $\vert 1-x \vert$,it should be  $\vert 1-x^2 \vert$.

Comment: It's $\sqrt 2,$ not $2.$ Also, what happened to negative values of $x?$

Comment: @PKStyles: your original question had $x$ with no power on it.

Comment: @zhw.: please read the original version of the question. It is not my fault that the OP edited the question after my answer was posted.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. Sorry.

Comment: No worries. It is not worth editing, since your answer is already there. Upvoted.

Comment: @MartinArgerami:apologies for editing the op after posting your answer.

Comment: @MartinArgerami:But, i mentioned about the edit in comment below your post.

Comment: @MartinArgerami:Sorry again,its my fault that i made an edit after posting your answer  ;-(.I hope you will not take it seriously .

Comment: Don't worry. It's an unavoidable consequence of how the site works: you ask a question with a typo, and an answer is posted that becomes irrelevant when the typo is corrected. Not the first time, nor the last one either.

Comment: @MartinArgerami:will you please edit your answer corresponding to the edited post,it'll be helpful for future learners.